# Run Webstorm as privileged user

Tags: users, ide, flatpak

I want to update the Webstorm IDE. I get the following error message.

```
WebStorm does not have write access to /app/extra/webstorm. Please run it by a privileged user to update.
```

WebStorm was installed from a flatpak from Ubuntu Software Center. When I right-click on Webstorms laucher icon and click Show details Ubuntu Software Center opens with the below screen.

The executable is located at

```
/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.jetbrains.WebStorm//x86_64/stable/3ed7173f533071abd544a5ff0859eb0b8a8ceb60935d7e2ab3cce3fac03ccabf/files/extra/webstorm/bin/webstorm.sh
```

How can I run Webstorm by a privileged user?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following steps-

1. Open the installation directory of Web Storm (`dpkg --listfiles webstorm` or `which webstorm`)
2. Find the executable (i.e., webstorm.sh)
3. Run as sudo `sudo ./webstorm.sh`
4. Update

Comment: I don't know the installation directory. How can I find it?

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: Through ubuntu software center.

Comment: Run this command `dpkg --listfiles webstorm` or `which webstorm` and post the result

Comment: dpkg-query: package 'webstorm' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: what is the output for `which WebStorm`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98483/discussion-between-digiwizkid-and-michael-h).

Comment: I found the executable with https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem
and using the command
find . -name "*.sh"
in
/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.jetbrains.WebStorm .